# Go back to Spring shell prompt after printing to Stdout

Tags: prompt, spring-shell

I'm currently working with Spring Shell. My problem is that whenever I print something to stdout, the program doesn't go back to the prompt unless the user presses the Enter button. Are there possible ways to invoke the prompt?

Answer (score 0):

Max,

Since you have not provided any code, let me give you a couple of things to try. Instead of printing to stdout, you can return a string. There are disadvantages to this approach. You can try flushing stdout - `System.out.flush()`. Please see if either of these approaches work for you.

Sualeh.

Answer (score 0):

You can use return value for your methods:

```
@ShellMethod(value = "Some description", key = "hi")
public String hello() {
    return "Hello";
}
```

or:

```
@ShellMethod(value = "Some description", key = "hi")
public AttributedString hello() {
    AttributedStyle style = AttributedStyle.DEFAULT.foreground(AttributedStyle.BLUE);
    return new AttributedString("Hello", style);
}
```